# Get all posts of a given user with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get all posts of the currently logged in user using mongodb.

Using Node & Passport as well.

My code currently works to find all posts of hard coded username. However I am needing to find all posts of the currently logged in username. My code below returns the posts for the specified user. How would I go about making it so it would show the currently logged in user's posts? 
Thanks!

```
app.get("/author", function(req, res){
    Cards.find({"author.username": "AndrewLeonardi"}, function(err, author){
    if (err){
    console.log("ERROR!");
     } else { 
res.render("done.ejs", {Cards: author, currentUser: req.user});
}
});
});
```

Comment: Did you try to pass req.user instead of your hardcoded user name?

Comment: `{ "author.username": req.user.username }` to be more precise?

Comment: Yeah it returns an error. Correct syntax? Cards.find({"author.username": "req.user"}

Comment: Ahhh!!  Chridam that worked! Thank you! Been stuck on that for hours!